# MVC Entity Framework Mapper to View Model to Update table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mapper

Again...

I am doing a MVC with EF5 App. I have a Users Entity, that EF bind with Users table in Database... Looks like this.

```
public partial class Users
{
    public long User_id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "LastName cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProcessState_id { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }

    [Required,Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "El País es Obligatorio")]
    public int Country_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpDateTime { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^.{5,}$", ErrorMessage = "Minimum 3 characters required")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Password cannot be longer than 9 characters.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public string CodArea { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual Countries Countries { get; set; }
    public virtual ProcessStates ProcessStates { get; set; }
    public virtual States States { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] // Does not effect with your database
    [RegularExpression(@"^.{5,}$", ErrorMessage = "Minimum 3 characters required")]
    [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password cannot be longer than 9 characters.")]
    [Compare("Password")]
    public virtual string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Model Class that i use it in my Create View....

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public Users user { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableCountries { get; set; }
}
```

My Create Method in the Controller gets a `UserViewModel` instance...

My Create Method looks like this.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(UserViewModel model, System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase image = null)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.user.ProcessState_id = Security.WAITING;
            model.user.Rol_id = Security.ROL_PUBLIC;
            model.user.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
            model.user.IP = Request.UserHostAddress;
            model.user.Url = UserValidation.EncriptacionURL(model.user.Email);
            if (image != null)
            {
              //  product.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
                model.user.Picture= new byte[image.ContentLength];
                image.InputStream.Read(model.user.Picture, 0, image.ContentLength);
            }
            _db.Users.Add(model.user);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        model.AvailableCountries = GetCountries();
        return View(model);
    }
    catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
    {
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

So far so good.

For my Edit View, i need less properties from User class, so I have a new class with the properties I need. This class is called `UserEditView`.

```
public class UserEditView
{
    public long User_id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "LastName cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required, Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "El País es Obligatorio")]
    public int Country_id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpDateTime { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public string CodArea { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Countries Countries { get; set; }
}
```

I also create a new Model for Edit View, called `UserEditViewModel` and looks like this.

```
public class UserEditViewModel
{
    public UserEditView user { get; set; }
     public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableCountries { get; set; }
}
```

On my Edit method, I use `Mapper` to bind `User` entity with `UserEditView`

```
public ViewResult Edit(int User_id=3)
{
    Users users = _db.Users
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.User_id == User_id);

    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Users, UserEditView>();
    });

    IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    UserEditView userEditView = mapper.Map<Users, UserEditView>(users);

    var model = new UserEditViewModel
    {
        user = userEditView,
        AvailableCountries = GetCountries(),
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

My problem arise when I want to Update the User table.

The Edit method gets `UserEditViewModel` instance.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(UserEditViewModel model, System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase image = null)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {}
    }
}
```

`UserEditViewModel` has an instance of `UserEditView` but I need an instance of `Users` in order to EF updates Users Table.

I need to Map again?
How can I get a Users Instance?

I add the following Class

```html
 public static class AutoMapperBootStrapper
    {
        public static void BootStrap()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Users, UserEditView>();
                cfg.CreateMap<UserEditView, Users>();
            });
            IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        }
```

And I add in my Global.asax

```html
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AutoMapperBootStrapper.BootStrap();
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
```

then in the controller... i do

```html
 public ViewResult Edit(int User_id=3)
        {
            Users users = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(p => p.User_id == User_id);

 UserEditView userEditView = Mapper.Map<Users, UserEditView>(users);
}
```

But `Mapper.Map` have an error... it says Mapper is not instantiated.

the problem is because I defined more than one Mapper. If i define just one, it Works fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to Map again? How can I get a Users Instance?

You could get the User model from your database using the id and then map the properties that you need to be updated from the view model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserEditViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase image = null)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Validation failed => redisplay the Edit form so that the
        // user can correct the errors
        return View(model);
    }

    var user = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(p => p.User_id == model.user.User_id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        // no user with the specified id has been found in the database =>
        // there's nothing to update
        return NotFound();
    }

    // This will map only the properties of the user object that
    // are part of the view model
    Mapper.Map<Users, UserEditView>(model.user, user);

    // at this stage you could manually update some properties that
    // have not been mapped such as the uploaded image

    // finally persist the changes to the database
    _db.SaveChanges();

    // redirect to some other action to show the updated users
    return RedirectToAction("users");
}
```

Also the code you have shown in your question:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Users, UserEditView>();
});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

This is absolutely **NOT** something that you should be doing inside a controller action. AutoMapper mappings should be configured only once per application lifetime, ideally when your application starts, i.e. for a web application that would be `Application_Start` in Global.asax. In a controller action you should only use the already configured mappings. I strongly recommend you going through the AutoMapper's documentation for getting better understanding of how to use this framework.

Quote from the [`documentation`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started#where-do-i-configure-automapper):

> **Where do I configure AutoMapper?**
>
> If you're using the static Mapper method, configuration should only
>   happen once per AppDomain. That means the best place to put the
>   configuration code is in application startup, such as the Global.asax
>   file for ASP.NET applications. Typically, the configuration
>   bootstrapper class is in its own class, and this bootstrapper class is
>   called from the startup method. The bootstrapper class should call
>   Mapper.Initialize to configure the type maps.

Comment: IF I define MapperConfiguration in Global Asax, in order to access  'IMapper mapper' from the Controller, I have to define it as Public,  and call UserEditView userEditView = mapper.Map<Users, UserEditView>(users);
from 'Controller'..?

Comment: You could use the static `Mapper.Map<TSource, TDest>` method as shown in my answer. Or inject the Mapper.Engine into your controller if you want to have better abstraction over the mapping logic. Still your mapping configuration should happen only once per AppDomain lifetime, i.e. in your Application_Start.

Comment: Did you configure it in your `Application_Start`?

Comment: I added how i have my Global and my controller. thanks

Comment: In your `Application_Start`: `Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>());`. And now in your controller you could use: `Mapper.Map<Order, OrderDto>(src, dest);`. That's all you need. What you have shown now in your question is that you are attempting to create some instance of a Mapper inside your `Application_Start` which is not needed. Everything is nicely explained in the documentation. All that it takes is head over it and read it: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: Darin.. It Works as you said, but the problem arise because I define two Mapping... because I need the reverse too. I need
'Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()); ' and
'Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<OrderDto, Order>()); so, that when I have the error

Comment: But why are you initializing the Mapper twice??? You should do it like that: `Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>(); cfg.CreateMap<OrderDto, Order>(); });`. OK, now please take some time to read the documentation because everything you need to know is there. You are wasting more time by doing it in some small steps rather than getting a deeper understanding of the framework you are using by reading its doc.